# C++ correct data structure

Tags: c++

I am looking for the correct data structure to store the number of characters of a given type in an incoming stream, letter by letter. I know the size of the alphabet in advance (about 10), but the stream will be about a 1gb. Main criteria is rapid access. Could use a list with an appropriately chosen `enum` to make things clearer, but is this the best way?

Comment: The "best" way depends on the circumstances and personal opinion. How about a map (char value -> usigned long long count) ?

Comment: What purpose of data structure? Storing data? Processing?

Comment: Something contiguous `int count[10]` or `std::vector<int> count(10, 0)`. But I think this depends a lot on the algorithm you will use.

Comment: i'd recommend std::map<char,unsigned int>

Comment: will be using to store data from the stream in step one. After than there is an additional step where each of the 10 numbers will be used a small number of times for other calculations. Main criteria is rapid access

Comment: @user3684792. If rapid access is the big thing. The contiguous data layout is better; it'll help avoid cache misses. Get the contiguous right for both the container and the data type.

Comment: ok, will use an int array or a vector. Is there performance of these approximately the same for many iterations of incrementing by one? I am leaning towards the former as I have a fixed alphabet size

Comment: @user3684792. About the same - I would not expect a reasonable difference once the data is loaded into the cache

Comment: If the character type is small (not greater than word width), I wouldn't bother with indirection but simply store the characters as is instead of keys to an alphabet. What type of characters are you going to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the performance requirements, consider a **layout that is contiguous in memory**; thus helping reduce the cache misses.

Something like;

```
const std::size_t SIZE = 10;
int count[SIZE] = {};
// or
std::vector<int> count(SIZE, 0);
```

If you need to store the count together with the character, then a "pair" may help;

```
struct Datum {
  Datum() : c('\0'), count(0) {}
  char c; // assuming the "alphabet" is in the char range
  int count;
};

std::vector<Datum> count(SIZE);
```

[Herb Sutter](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661) and [Bjarne](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style) offer some material and empirical evidence as to why `std::vector` should be favoured. As always, **measurements should be made** to verify the performance given your data structure, algorithm and associated data accesses etc.

Comment: `int count[256];` may avoid the indirection alphabet->index.

Answer (score 0):

A simple array would work best:

`int counters[SIZE_OF_ALPHABET];`

Answer (score 0):

For storing you can try make alphabet encoding table and simple char array (char is enough to store 1 of 10 different characters). Like:

```
map<int, char> m;
m['A'] = 1;
m['B'] = 2;
...
char data[SIZE];

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    int ch = read();
    data[i] = m[ch];
}
```

Or compress 2 items into one char.